# Problems Using LOOKUP() in Excel

Tags: excel, lookup

I want to use the LOOKUP function to match values according to their category (see picture).

It worked so far as expected, but when I enlarge the range of the lookup_vector, it breaks, meaning that once I get the expected value, once #N/A.

In one row I have `=LOOKUP(T2,'Electrode Clalc'!P3:P36,'Electrode Clalc'!E3:E36)` , in the other I have `=LOOKUP(T3,'Electrode Clalc'!P3:P37,'Electrode Clalc'!E3:E37)`.

Case 1 where it works:
[image: Case 1 where it works]

Case 2 where it doesn't:
[image: Case 2 where it doesn't]

P36/E36 and P37/E36 contain both similar code:

P36: `=0.8*(D36-N33)*(1-LOOKUP(A32,'LFP Calculations'!A2:A32,'LFP Calculations'!E2:E32))`
E36: `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A32, 100),"-",LEFT(B32, 100),"-",LEFT(C36,100))`

and

P37:`=0.8*(D37-N33)*(1-LOOKUP(A32,'LFP Calculations'!A2:A32,'LFP Calculations'!E2:E32))`
E37:`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A32, 100),"-",LEFT(B32, 100),"-",LEFT(C37,100))`

[image: Sheet]

I would appreciate if someone could help me.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

[image: Showing that it works with the correct Number]

Comment: Why aren't you locking the ranges? like `$P$3:$P$36`

Comment: I selected the it manually, thus Excel wrote `P3:P36` by itself. changing it to `$P$3:$P$36` didn't solve the problem though :/

Comment: Can you check each value in other sheet something like ´$T$3=P3´ and fill down until ´P37´? if exist the same value at least one of the 34 cells will say ´TRUE´. It is a way that I do to detect where is the error. Sometimes a single space ruins the formula.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did as told and checked all the P__. `P36`as well as `P37` give false. I now even deleted the entries in `P37`and still get a #N/A

Comment: I am seeing your pictures and it is not clear for me why in the `[Batteries]` field the code ends with BT and in the other sheet it ends with a number `{01, 02, ..., 05}` this doesn't match with your formula.

Answer (score 0):

In the formula where it does not work:

`=LOOKUP(T3,'Electrode Clalc'!P3:P37,'Electrode Clalc'!E3:E37)`

It is because:

- the value in `T3` cannot be found in `P3:P37` (check for spaces before or after);
- or if it is found, on the same row of the found value in column `E` there is an error, thus it returns the error correctly;

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the first point already. When I insert `P3:P36`, then I get the correct result. (See Edit).

I do not see, however, why it would find `T3` on `P36`, as it is just `- - ` like `P36`